# How to send session ID cookie in a cross-origin request?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using the Peloton API to generate statistics based on workout data grabbed from their API. Certain API requests require the user to be logged in, which can be done by sending your username and password to /auth/login. It returns a session ID that is needed to get those locked requests, such as workout history. The session ID is seemingly sent as a cookie (using credentials: 'include').

When I set credentials to include, it says `"Access to fetch at (url) from origin (my site) has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '\*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.` How do I fix this? My code is below.

```
async function loginAndGetData(username, password) {
    const info = { 'username_or_email': username, 'password': password };
    const response = await fetch("https://pelotoncors.herokuapp.com/https://api.onepeloton.com/auth/login",
{
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(info)
});
    const loginInfo = await response.json();
    const workoutInfo = await fetch('https://pelotoncors.herokuapp.com/https://api.onepeloton.com/api/user/' + loginInfo.user_id + '/workouts?limit=1234567890',
{
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
});
}
```

Comment: Could you explaine the use of `https://pelotoncors.herokuapp.com` in the the url ? I don't understand the purpose of that, why not just call the api directly ?

Comment: Without that, the console would throw errors related to CORS stuff, after reading online it seemed like cors-anywhere was necessary so I installed it on a heroku app to bypass the CORS restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

So I identified multiple problems:

1. Paleton doesn't have an official API or even an API doc (that doesn't make it impossible to use their API, but it can be difficult, and I would be cautious with that)
2. CORS
3. cors-anywhere

Logically, to prevent the use of the API by anybody, Paleton, like anybody else who builds a serious API, decided to put CORS headers on their responses, which is obviously not only from a security standpoint reasonable, but can be quite annoying because it makes it basically impossible to use the API from the browsers because the browser enforces the CORS-headers that are being set on responses by the servers.

So your first idea with cors-anywhere seems rational, but doesn't work because you use `credentials: 'include'` which requires the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to NOT be set to wildcard `*`.

If you are not familiar of what all that above means, let me run you through it:
In your above code, which I assume because of the above error message you run on a browser, you try to make a fetch call to cors-anywhere with the URL of the API and userId. Cors-anywhere makes the call to the API for you and ignores the CORS-Headers (it can do that because it is just a *policy* created for browsers to increase security), send you the data it gets from the API back **BUT** with the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' (by default) set to wildcard `*`. Because you use `credentials: 'include'` though, which requires the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header do NOT be set on wildcard, your browser detects a CORS-policy violation, and you get the above error.

So what can you do now ?

1. Either you offload the API calls to your own backend (which is BTW always a better option), ignore the CORS by yourself and set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header appropriately or
2. Maybe there is a query you can add to the URL for cors-anywhere to change the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'? (But I don't know that) or
3. You look for an alternative

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is  your backend on Heroku, you need to set header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true on your backend.

Comment: He doesn't own the backend, thats the problem, its a quick service to avoid CORS